# Powershell Regex match statement

Tags: regex, powershell

Trying to get nxxxxx number as the output from below input,

```
uniqueMember: uid=n039833,ou=people,ou=networks,o=test,c=us
uniqueMember: uid=N019560, ou=people, ou=Networks, o=test, c=Us
```

Tried,

```
[Regex]::Matches($item, "uid=([^%]+)\,")
```

but this gives,

```
Groups   : {0, 1}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 14
Length   : 43
Value    : uid=N018315,ou=people,ou=Networks,o=test,

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 18
Length   : 38
Value    : N018315,ou=people,ou=Networks,o=test
```

Some help with improving the match statement appreciated ..

Comment: You can ignore matching a comma `uid=([^%,]+),` and get the capture group 1 value https://regex101.com/r/VEi4M1/1

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
[Regex]::Matches($s, "(?<=uid=)[^,]+").Value
```

To save in an object variable:

```
$matches = [Regex]::Matches($s, "(?<=uid=)[^,]+").Value
```

Output:

```
n039833
N019560
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=uid=)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `uid=` text to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^,]+` - one or more chars other than a comma.

Comment: you can use `[Regex]::Matches( ).Value`, powershell can do the enumeration of the property values for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a capture group and prevent matching `,` and if you don't want to match `%` you can also exclude that.

```
$s = "uniqueMember: uid=n039833,ou=people,ou=networks,o=test,c=us\nuniqueMember: uid=N019560, ou=people, ou=Networks, o=test, c=Us"
[regex]::Matches($s,'uid=([^,]+)') | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Output

```
n039833
N019560
```

Note that in the current pattern there should be a trailing comma present. If that is not ways the case, you can omit matching that from the pattern. If you only want to exclude matching a comma, the pattern will be:

```
uid=([^,]+)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, was trying to format .ldif from Unix team to import to AD, DN is diff between systems ..